# While Run Facebook Login App it Shows Error

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk

Here in my Main activity and I follow all the facebook Concole Methood.
When I tried to run the app.it shows an error that

> Login error: There was an error while login your app, try again later

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        textView1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        textView2 = findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        textView3 = findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        circleImageView = findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        loginButton.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("first_name","last_name","email","id","image_url"));
        checkLoginStatus();

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
                {

                }

            @Override
            public void onCancel()
                {


                }
            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error)
                {

                }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

        AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker=new AccessTokenTracker()
        {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken)
                {
                    if(currentAccessToken==null)
                        {
                            textView1.setText("");
                            textView2.setText("");
                            textView3.setText("");
                            circleImageView.setImageResource(0);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"User Logged out",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                     else
                         {
                            loadUserProfile(currentAccessToken);
                         }
                }
        };

    private void loadUserProfile(AccessToken newacesstoken)
        {
            GraphRequest request=GraphRequest.newMeRequest(newacesstoken,new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback()
                {
                     @Override
                     public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response)
                        {
                             try
                                {
                                    String first_name=object.getString("first_name");
                                    String last_name=object.getString("last_name");
                                    String email=object.getString("email");
                                    String id=object.getString("id");
                                    String  image_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=normal";

                                    textView1.setText(first_name +" "+last_name);
                                    textView2.setText(email);
                                    textView3.setText(id);
                                    //RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
                                    //requestOptions.dontAnimate();
                                    Picasso.get().load(image_url).into(circleImageView);
                                }
                             catch (JSONException e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                        }
                });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "first_name,last_name,email,id,image_url");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
        }

            private void checkLoginStatus()
    {
        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()!=null)
        {
            loadUserProfile(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());

        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: When do you see the error? In Facebook login screen or in your MainActivity when you return from Facebook Login screen?

Comment: facebook login screen